# how to convert from Newline Delimited text file to csv with Powershell

Tags: powershell, command-line, command-line-interface, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a text file containing the below test data:

```
1234
\\test
QATest
Silk
Chrome
```

I have a requirement to convert this text file into a CSV file using Powershell which would look somewhat like

```
1234,\\test,QATest,Silk,Chrome
```

Could anybody please suggest the right way?

Comment: Please don't use every only half way matching tag - **read** the tag info. The different  powershell tags usually exclude the others. [You were already told so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54197624/how-to-add-data-to-last-column-of-csv-using-powershell#comment95222457_54197624)

Comment: Thats cool.Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Read all the lines in, then concatenate them using [the `-join` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_join):

```
$originalLines = Get-Content .\input.txt
$originalLines -join ',' |Set-Content .\output.csv
```

Comment: @AbhishekPandey great, you're welcome! If my answer solves your problem, please consider marking it "accepted" by clicking the checkmark to the left - it'll make the question figure as "answered" and you'll get rep for it :)